# 2-Dimensional Convolution - How to implement in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing, convolution

I've been banging the head against the wall for quite a bit now. 
I'm used to working with Matlab's `conv2` function, which does the convolution by itself.

However, I just fail to implement it properly in Java. I would provide a code snippet, but its all messed up. I'll try to get it clear and post (it's actually 4:30 am here and I'm still struggling at this..).

Can anyone please post a working code method that does the 2d convolution between two 2-dimensional arrays of the same size in Java?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Re, `"can anyone please post a working code method that does the 2d convolution between two 2-dimensional arrays of the same size in Java?"`: As currently written, this is not a true question but rather a begging for code which is not appropriate for this site. Please change this by showing your code and asking a specific answerable question before your question gets closed.

Comment: Seriously, a cursory Google search yield the exact function.

Answer (score 2):

A little Googling never hurts.  [This code](http://code.google.com/p/clasificaciondepizzas/source/browse/trunk/ClasificacionDePizzas/src/clasificaciondepizzas/operations/canny/Convolution.java) might help you.  In particular,

```
public static double[][] convolution2D(double[][] input,
            int width, int height,
            double[][] kernel,
            int kernelWidth,
            int kernelHeight) {
        int smallWidth = width - kernelWidth + 1;
        int smallHeight = height - kernelHeight + 1;
        double[][] output = new double[smallWidth][smallHeight];
        for (int i = 0; i < smallWidth; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < smallHeight; ++j) {
                output[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < smallWidth; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < smallHeight; ++j) {
                output[i][j] = singlePixelConvolution(input, i, j, kernel,
                        kernelWidth, kernelHeight);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: i did, could not find anything worthy of use. will try this segment. thanks!